# In .NET authentication the application not confirmed the account because the code is null, why?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, razor-pages

I am using .NET authentication, the application (Razor Pages) not confirmed the account because the code is null but it's exists in the link, why is that?

[the code is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fljC3.jpg)

[code exists in the link i received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiaPB.jpg)

I deployed the database and the application for free hosting because I thought that's the reason but it's not.

[& is not exist in 'callbackUrl'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5wv2.jpg)

[& is exist in 'confirmCode'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWW3C.jpg)

i think the problem is here:
var confirmCode = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);

Comment: Looks to me like `&amp;code` is what you receive

Comment: yes, what does that's mean?

Comment: My guess is that your code is adding the extra `&`

Comment: i add 2 photos for the problem can you check them?

Comment: Why are your encoding a URL?

Comment: it's the default scaffolding identity from Microsoft, I fixed it and removed the encoding. thanks for your note about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i think the problem is here: `var confirmCode = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);`

Yes, it is. HTML encoding is used for encoding HTML for display in a web page. It converts HTML characters to their entities (e.g. `<` becomes `&lt;` and  `&` becomes `&amp;`) so that you don't embed actual HTML into your page.

When encoding a URL, you should use the `WebUtility.UrlEncode` method instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=net-7.0, then URL-safe characters like `&` are not altered, and your query string is understood correctly by the model binder.

Answer (score 0):

i removed this code :

var confirmCode = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl);

and send the 'callbackUrl' instead 'confirmCode'.